# finding out which ports a program/process ist listening to - lsof, netstat

Tags: java, shell, ubuntu, netstat, lsof

Under Ubuntu I'm having an interactive program that I'm suspecting it is hanging listening on a specific port, don't know which one.

It is a shell script that invokes a java command in its last line.

How can I easily find out the ports it is listening to in the state when it is "hanging"?

I tried to put lsof in front of the command but a huge path is written out and it says "lsof: path too long"

```
lsof -c java  ${JAVA_OPTS} -classpath "${SERVLET_API}:${JSP_API}:${OPENCMS_CLASSPATH}:${TOMCAT_CLASSPATH}:${OPENCMS_BASE}/classes" org.opencms.main.CmsShell -base="${OPENCMS_BASE}" "$@"
```

Comment: You could try using netstat instead of lsof to see what ports are listening for connections.

Comment: Try to look for the name of the program you suspect like this lsof -i -P | grep <your_prog_name>

Comment: Listening at a port doesn't cause hangs, but *reading* from a port causes *blocks.*

Comment: Which version of Java?

Answer (score 1):

Split that in several commands. First start your application with `java ...`. Then you can use `jps` to see the process ID of the new Java process (`jps` should be in the same folder as `java`).

Now you can use `lsof -np <id>` to get a list of file descriptors.

But Java programs can also hang in loops. To see what the program is currently doing, use `jstack` or `jconsole`.

Comment: jstackPID  didn't yield any output. jstack -F PID gave a stacktrace saying .NoSuchSymbolException: Could not find symbol "gHotSpotVMTypes"

Comment: jconsole was unable to connect to the process

Comment: @Krischu: Re `jstack`: Make sure you use the correct version of the program for your version of Java. Check the value of `$JAVA_HOME` and the output of `readlink -f $(which java)`

Comment: For `jconsole`, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html